How to cover html lines in a php file using phpunit test?
I'm currently doing code coverage tests for a WordPress child theme and having issue to cover php files in the patterns folder. example below is for patterns/header.php.

If I created a test file and included the file using require, I got risky warning from phpunit
There was 1 risky test:

1) headerTest::testheader
This test executed code that is not listed as code to be covered or used:
- /opt/homebrew/var/www/wp-content/themes/flex/patterns/header.php:10
- /opt/homebrew/var/www/wp-content/themes/flex/patterns/header.php:11
- /opt/homebrew/var/www/wp-content/themes/flex/patterns/header.php:12
- /opt/homebrew/var/www/wp-content/themes/flex/patterns/header.php:13
- /opt/homebrew/var/www/wp-content/themes/flex/patterns/header.php:14
- /opt/homebrew/var/www/wp-content/themes/flex/patterns/header.php:15
- /opt/homebrew/var/www/wp-content/themes/flex/patterns/header.php:16
- /opt/homebrew/var/www/wp-content/themes/flex/patterns/header.php:29

/opt/homebrew/var/www/wp-content/tests/themes/patterns/headerTest.php:23

And it didn't get counted in the coverage data.
<file name="/opt/homebrew/var/www/wp-content/themes/flex/patterns/header.php">
  <line num="10" type="stmt" count="0"/>
  <line num="11" type="stmt" count="0"/>
  <line num="12" type="stmt" count="0"/>
  <line num="13" type="stmt" count="0"/>
  <line num="14" type="stmt" count="0"/>
  <line num="15" type="stmt" count="0"/>
  <line num="16" type="stmt" count="0"/>
  <line num="29" type="stmt" count="0"/>
  <metrics loc="41" ncloc="35" classes="0" methods="0" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="8" coveredstatements="0" elements="8" coveredelements="0"/>
</file>

Other themes files we successfuly covered with test files using attributes such as #[CoversFunction] and #[CoversClass].
I asked AI for help to produce test code below but the header code still considered as not covered and added a risky statement.

HeaderTest::testHeaderStructure
This test does not define a code coverage target but is expected to do so

<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class HeaderTest extends TestCase
{
  protected $headerContent;

  protected function setUp(): void
  {
    $this->headerContent = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../../themes/flex/patterns/header.php');
  }

  public function testHeaderStructure()
  {
    $this->assertStringContainsString('<div class="wp-block-group alignwide header-container', $this->headerContent, 'Header container not found.');
    $this->assertStringContainsString('<div class="wp-block-group alignfull logo-container', $this->headerContent, 'Logo container not found.');
    $this->assertStringContainsString('<div class="wp-block-group alignfull flex-navbar-wrapper', $this->headerContent, 'Navbar wrapper not found.');
  }
}


Can I ask what your actual tests of these types of files would be? I don't know if I've ever written unit tests that covers template files, in any platform, and I'm trying to think what I'd even put in there.

HTML template files are ignored but since pattens files are html inside a php files, they are required to be covered.
It's a wordpress child theme. It's not a complicated theme but the client wanted a code review using sonar cube with all green colors. now the issue is the code coverage is still red because the patterns php file.
